# ActionListener is abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed -- despite containing that very method

Tags: java, swing, overriding, actionlistener, abstract

So I'm getting the error `Class is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener`

I am aware of the origin of this error but what confuses me is that I have that method.

```
public static ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Clock cl = new Clock();
        if(seconds<59){
            seconds++;
        }else{
            seconds=0;
            if(minutes<59){
                minutes++;
            }else{
                minutes=0;
                if(hours<12){
                    hours++;
                }else{
                    hours=0;
                }
            }
        }

        cl.repaint();   
    }
};'
```

Not quite sure what's going on. Any help? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: context including imports and related methods

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.Object.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.awt.geom.*;


public class Clock extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
public static int seconds = 0;
public static int minutes = 0;
public static int hours = 9;

public static ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Clock cl = new Clock();
        if(seconds<59){
            seconds++;
        }else{
            seconds=0;
            if(minutes<59){
                minutes++;
            }else{
                minutes=0;
                if(hours<12){
                    hours++;
                }else{
                    hours=0;
                }
            }
        }

        cl.repaint();   
    }
};
public static Timer timer = new Timer(1000, taskPerformer);

public static void main(String[] args){
    Clock cl = new Clock();
    init();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
public static void init(){
    timer.start();
}
public Clock() {
    super("Clock");
    timer.addActionListener(this);

}'
```

Comment: please write more major tags like the language **java**

Comment: please add the imports to the code.

Comment: It compiles on my machine.  What version of Java are you running?  Are you positive the compiler error goes with this line of code?

Comment: @JeanneBoyarsky The error comes from the line where i make the class, pointing at the word class.

Comment: @M.Sameer Done, and added more context

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem wasn't in the original code snippet you posted.  Your class `Clock` does not implement `actionPerformed()`.  The `taskPerformer` object does.  But the code is complaining that `taskPerformer` is an `ActionListener` but Clock is not.

Also, you don't appear to use `taskPerformer` anywhere so why do you need the anonymous class.  You could just define `actionPerformed()` in Clock and be done with it.

I see two ways to deal with this.  (I've omitted some irrelevant code to make the technique clearer).

**Option 1 - Use clock as the listener**

```
    public class Clock extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public static int seconds = 0;
    public static int minutes = 0;
    public static int hours = 9;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // code
    }

    public Timer timer;

    public Clock() {
        super("Clock");
        timer = new Timer(1000, this);
        timer.addActionListener(this);    
    }
}
```

**Option 2 - Use the anonymous listener**

```
    public class Clock extends JFrame {
    public static int seconds = 0;
    public static int minutes = 0;
    public static int hours = 9;

    public static ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // insert code here
        }
    };

    public static Timer timer = new Timer(1000, taskPerformer);

    public Clock() {
        super("Clock");
        timer.addActionListener(taskPerformer);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohhh okay, thank you! 
Also I use taskPerformer with 
    'public static Timer timer = new Timer(1000, taskPerformer);'

Comment: Hmm, trying it out I get the same error in addition to the symbol: class actionPerformed not being found.  Can you explain how to implement this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replace `ActionEvent e` with `java.awt.event.ActionEvent e` as follows:

```
@Override  
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
    //do something here
}
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Worked for  my code also. I wonder why ActionEvent e dont work.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of putting is that, if a class implements ActionPerformed, the action must be performed within that classes boundaries.