# Java no abstract and does not override error

Tags: java

I keep getting an not abstract and does not override error. I can't find the mistake either. Where did I go wrong? I checked if the curly braces were on the right place and they seem to be. This is the exact error message "addNumbers is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener

Missing javadoc. "

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class addNumbers extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();

    JLabel num1 = new JLabel("First Number:  ");
    JTextField number1 = new JTextField(10);

    JLabel num2 = new JLabel("Second Number:  ");
    JTextField number2 = new JTextField(10);

    JButton sumbutton = new JButton("Sum Numbers");
    JButton exitbutton = new JButton("Exit");
    JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");

    JLabel result = new JLabel("The result is: ");
    JLabel add = new JLabel("");


public addNumbers(){

    Container con = getContentPane();
    con.setLayout(flow);
    con.add(num1);
    con.add(number1);
    con.add(num2);
    con.add(number2);
    con.add(sumbutton);
    con.add(exitbutton);
    con.add(reset);
    con.add(result);

    sumbutton.addActionListener(this);
    exitbutton.addActionListener(this);
    reset.addActionListener(this);

}//end addNumbers containers

public static void main(String[] args){
    addNumbers nframe = new addNumbers();
    nframe.setSize(300,300);
    nframe.setVisible(true);
    nframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    nframe.setTitle("Calculations");

}//end main

public void getAction(ActionEvent e){
    Object source = e.getSource();

    if(source == sumbutton){
        String num1 = number1.getText();
        String num2 = number2.getText();

        double n1 = Double.parseDouble(num1);
        double n2 = Double.parseDouble(num2);
        double total = n1+n2;
        String result = "" + total;
        //convert back to spring to output
        add.setText(result);;     
    }

    else if(source == reset){
        number1.setText("");
        number2.setText("");
        add.setText("");
    }
    else{
        System.exit(0);
    }

}//end of getAction


}//end addNumbers
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActionListener is abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed -- despite containing that very method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813580/actionlistener-is-abstract-and-does-not-override-abstract-method-actionperformed)

Comment: Can you reduce this code to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2):

As the error message clearly states, your class does not implement the method `actionPerformed` which is required for classes that implement `ActionListener`.

Either remove the interface if you don't need it or add the method if you plan on using it.

The "is not abstract" part in the error message refers to the fact that it would be OK for your class to not implement all interface methods if it was an `abstract class`, in which case classes that inherit from it would be required to implement them instead.